# Why is Mozilla Firefox not showing any downloading status If I am downloading the file?

Tags: firefox, download, mega

In Mozilla Firefox browser, I am downloading file from mega.nz:

[image]

But download section of the browser is empty:

[image]

Why is Mozilla Firefox not showing any downloading status If I am downloading the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mega.nz does not download files via the normal method. They use [their own tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994554/download-files-like-mega-co-nz/15994861#15994861) to speed up downloads. This means Firefox cannot display the download status. This is normal.

Comment: I don't think the goal is to speed anything up. It's rather about the decryption being implemented client-side.

Comment: @gronostaj Yeah, I think it's both.